# Laravel Redirect to route with Parameters

Tags: laravel, redirect, eloquent

This is my code:

```
return redirect()->route('edit.brand',$id)->with(array( 'brand' => $brand, 'errorName' => $errorName, 'errorCode' => $errorCode));
```

The result is that, in the FORM of route edit.brand. 
It's filled by data with $id, (do the route first and ignore all parameters in 'with' )
How can I show $errorName if they exist

Answer (score 2):

When You are redirecting to route, your parameters goes to flash session. So in `edit.brand` route You can access it with session helper like so:

```
session('errorName')
```

Comment: Excuse me! How to I show it in Form . I tried with {{ session('errorName') }} but not work, please tell me more, Thanks, Giedrius!

Comment: It should work the same way in views as it works in controller. Please make sure, that You are not redirected again from `edit.brand` route to some other page, because each redirect destroys flash session variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is for flash data not request parameters That you are using .

Use this one

```
return Redirect::route('user', array('nick' => $username));
```